# Missing Apps Menu Liferay

Tags: liferay, ubuntu-18.04, liferay-7

After Log in to marketplace from liferay portal. I can't find anymore apps menu to add some applications.

[image: App Manager]
[Server Linux Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zCvbF.png)

Comment: Do you have any piece of log to share? the startup log will probably tell us something.

Comment: This is some piece of log , I don't know it will help.
Because I'm a new user for liferay.

Comment: The log is not readable.. pls share it better.